# XNA: Slowing down draw intervals

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm drawing a tileset really quickly to visualize an algorithm, so I turned to XNA to do the drawing for me.  The problem is that it always draws as fast as possible, and I want to slow it down to instead draw every X milliseconds, where X is arbitrary according to a local variable.  For example, draw every 100ms.  I tried using IsFixedTimeStep and TargetElapsedTime, but all that did was fire off the right number of Updates but draw every X ms, resulting in missing all of the in-between steps.

Does anyone know how to get around this?  Here are my Draw and Update methods:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    // TODO: Add your update logic here
    if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        _engine.SpreadFire();
    }

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        _engine.InitializeBoardStates(5);
        SuppressDraw();
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

/// <summary>
/// This is called when the game should draw itself.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    for (var i = 0; i < _engine.BoardStates.Count; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < _engine.BoardStates[i].Count; j++)
        {
            var isOnFire = _engine.BoardStates[i][j];
            this.spriteBatch.Draw(isOnFire ? LitTile : NormalTile, new Rectangle(j * 10, i * 10, 10, 10), Color.White);
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

(I'd also take any suggestions on little things I've done wrong and/or inefficiently.  I only started looking at XNA this afternoon.)

Comment: Slow down your logic, not your drawing.

Comment: That makes sense, but any suggestions?  I can do thread delays and throw empty loops everywhere, but is there a better way of handling it in XNA?

Comment: I don't know any XNA specifics, but IMO timers are more clean than empty loops. Doesn't XNA automatically multi-thread parts of the code or something like that?

Comment: The algorithm itself merely calculates a board state.  So each time the algorithm fires, it puts the board in a new state.  Then the drawing happens.  So really, it isn't a matter of the algorithm being too fast -- that's the entire point of the algorithm -- it's that I need a way to throttle Update in such a way as to not trigger the whole mess off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try the following (or similar) in the Update method I believe it will achieve the desired outcome, although I haven't tested.

```
// This should restrict your code to running once per 100 ticks
if (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Ticks % 100 == 0)
{
    if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        _engine.SpreadFire();
    }

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        _engine.InitializeBoardStates(5);
        SuppressDraw();
    }
}
```

You could then use `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` or similar also, here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan(v=vs.110).aspx) for the TimeSpan struct. Also changing the value to mod by would affect how quickly it updates.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't just exit from the Draw routine if you aren't supposed to draw yet (as indicated by your X variable)? Just keep track of the last drawTime when you do draw, though.

Comment: It would skip drawing frames, but not delay the actual algorithm! Actually, it is worse than doing it fast.

Comment: Well - then I misunderstand what the OP wants. What do you want to have  a variable timestep? Update? Draw? Both? If one of them doesn't keep up it is likely to miss changes in the other, right?

Comment: The idea is to throttle both in such a way as to control when everything gets kicked off.  So I can say, for example, "Only calculate this X times a second."

Comment: If this "throttling" is dynamic, the only option you have is to check if the current update step needs to be executed or cancel it and wait for the next step. Also note that the Render/Update loops have to run a far faster rate than your actual updates/renders for them to not miss any information between iterations.